# Solving a System of Recursively Defined Equations in Mathematica

Tags: equation-solving, probability-or-statistics, recursion

I am trying to solve a system of equations in Mathematica where the variables are recursively defined. The system represents a probability distribution, and I want to find the values of the variables that satisfy the equations. However, I am encountering a recursion depth error, and I'm having difficulty resolving it.

Here is the Mathematica code I am using:

```
Clear[Y, p, pi]
equations = {
  pi[1] == p,
  Table[pi[i] == p (1 - p)^(i - 1) (Sum[pi[j], {j, 1, Y - i + 1}]), {i, 2, Y - 1}],
  pi[Y] == p (1 - p)^(Y - 1) pi[1],
  pi[Y + i] == p (1 + p) (1 - p)^(Y + i - 1), {i, 1, Infinity},
  Sum[pi[i], {i, 1, Infinity}] == 1
}

(* Solve the system of equations *)
solution = Solve[equations, Table[pi[i], {i, 1, Infinity}]]
```

Upon running this code, I encounter the error: $RecursionLimit: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded.

I suspect that there might be an issue with the recursive definition of the variables. Could someone please help me understand how to properly set up and solve a system of equations with such recursive definitions?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! First, there seems to be some syntacti errors in your definition of equations (for example, a `Table` is missing). Second, what are `Y` and `p`? Are these just two parameters? Do you know their values? Lastly, only first `Y` equations are recursive, the remaining ones are explicit. So you should separate the two. For example, solving the first `Y=5` equations:

Comment: `With[{Y = 5},equations = Flatten@{pi[1] == p,Table[pi[i] == p (1 - p)^(-1 + i) (Sum[pi[j], {j, 1, Y - i + 1}]), {i, 2, Y - 1}]};Echo[equations // Column, "Equations"];solution = Solve[equations, {p}~Join~Table[pi[i], {i, 1, Y - 1}]]
 ]`

Comment: Thank you for your help. `Y` and `p` are symbolic system parameters and I am trying to analytically solve for the steady-state distribution of a Markov Chain. Your example with `Y=5` does seem to give the right equations, but could you suggest how would I extend this to an arbitrary `Y`?